# Can the "t" letter be uttered as a flap t before the letter "h"?

Tags: pronunciation

I know the flap-t is usually used when the "t" is between vowels or between an "r" and a vowel, but I think I can also hear it betwenn vowels and the "h". And I noticed the same with the "g" I think.

For instance: wha(t) happend?

Am I right?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your 'g' example?

Comment: Yes, the t of "what happened" can be a voiceless flap.

Comment: I can't think of an example for that right now in which I heard it said that way, but I hear it from time to time.

Comment: Dunno what a "t-flap" is, but is *outhouse* an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, it is. How do you pronounce the "t" in that word?

Comment: @Greg: It can be several other things too - glottal stop is a favourite for me, but /r/ is fairly common in (particularly, *Northern*) BrE. Plus of course people will often go for cut-down versions of *What **has** happened?*, or *What **is** up?* where everything in the middle just reduces to /s/.

Comment: I have compared notes on this with my friend David Stampe, originally from NW Indiana (I'm from NW Ohio), and he has many more voiceless flaps than I.  Iirc, the t in words like "liquidity" is optionally voiceless for him, while I would always voice it.

Comment: Thank you, it's very helpful and interesting. Could you tell me, please, what's the difference between a voiceless and voiced flap-t? It's the first time I've heard that there are variations.